# Is PCC necessary for cert API?

Tags: sabre

I created a Dev Studio account and am able to successfully retrieve a v2 API token. When I try to use that token to make requests to other APIs, I run into issues. I have tried following the instructions at https://developer.sabre.com/docs/rest_apis/air/search/advanced_calendar_search/reference-documentation and https://developer.sabre.com/docs/rest_apis/air/search/bargain_finder_max/versions/v500/reference-documentation to send requests. The error I get back is:

```
    <h1>Error: Bad Request</h1>
    <h2>Your client has issued a malformed or illegal request.</h2>
```

Specifically looking at the advanced calendar search api, I am using the body copied right out of the reference documentation, with small updates made so that the dates are recent. I'm pretty confident that my headers are correct and my token is being sent correctly. Is there a way to figure out more information about what's going wrong? Do I need a PCC to test this out? That's the only thing I can think of so far that I might be missing.